# Unable to open DBF file on R

Tags: r, dbf

I'm trying to open a few .dbf files on R. I downloaded the foreign package in order to use the read.dbf function but doesn't seems to be working. Anyone can help me?
This is the script and the error message:

```
LTANTO18 <-read.dbf("LTANTO18.dbf")
**Error in read.dbf("LTANTO18.dbf") : unable to open DBF file**
```

Comment: You could install `maptools` and try using `dbf.read()` to open the file. The manual page for `read.dbf()` warns that it may not work for all ".dbf" files. If you have a spreadsheet program on your computer, try opening the file with that. If that works, export the file as a ".csv" file and use `read.csv()`.